# Active scripting is enabled on ie but my javascript is not showing up

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, internet-explorer, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have a site created using .net and the ajaxcontroltoolkit. When some users log on they do not see the controls on the page. I can duplicate this if I disable active scripting in ie. The problem is that the users I have spoken with have active scripting enabled. I have had them navigate to a site that tests javascript and it passes. Has anyone experienced this problem? If so what was your solution? Does anyone know what would cause this sort of behavior?

Comment: do you have a code sample? depending what code you are using you may find a setting that is still affecting execution.  e.g. there is a setting in Options... Advanced "Enable native XMLHTTP support" which toggles the use of XMLHTTPRequests via native JavaScript or using the ActiveX one.

Comment: In addition, what version(s) of IE are you/they using.

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following:

1. Add a `noscript` tag in one of your pages, this will confirm if this behavior is due to disabled active scripting or somthing else.

   `<noscript> Active Scripting Disabled </noscript>`
2. I.E have 4 different security zones (*Internet*, *Local Intranet*, *Trusted sites* and *Restricted sites*).  Make sure your site exists inside one with active scripting enabled.

Comment: I have tried both of these and scripts are enabled. I have had users try to put the site in the trusted sites zone both to no avail.